# Rect with stroke, the stroke line is mis-transformed when scaled

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have got a lot of helps from this site and contributors here, thanks. Now I have a question about the Rectangle in Fabric.js with stroke, as I used it as kind of placeholder for images and text, when I scaled it, the border line width is scaled too, I think it's kind a problem as I want to keep the border width not changed.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c1");

var el = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: "left",
    originY: "top",
    left: 5,
    top: 5,
    stroke: "#ccc",
    strokWidth: 1,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cornerSize: 6
});

canvas.add (el);
canvas.renderAll ();
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/9yb46/, try scale it horizontally. And a image is here too, and see the left border and right border width, supposed as same as top and bottom border, but not:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have miss-typed the name of the property in your fiddle : strokWidth - **e** is missing. But this is not the cause of the problem since the default value for the strokeWidth is 1.

The scaled stroke issue is the expected behavior and what you ask to do is not. Anyway, before you check my code, read [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/66) and [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/61) and maybe some more [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=fabricjs%20strokeWidth%20scale).

Then try this code to help with your needs, this will work perfectly only if you keep the scale ratio of your rectangle as 1:1 (scaleX = scaleY).

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrTuN/1/):

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c1");

var el = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: "left",
    originY: "top",
    left: 5,
    top: 5,
    stroke: "rgb(0,0,0)",
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cornerSize: 6
});

el.myCustomOptionKeepStrokeWidth = 1;
canvas.on({
    'object:scaling': function(e) {
        var obj = e.target;
        if(obj.myCustomOptionKeepStrokeWidth){
            var newStrokeWidth = obj.myCustomOptionKeepStrokeWidth / ((obj.scaleX + obj.scaleY) / 2);
            obj.set('strokeWidth',newStrokeWidth);
        }
    }
});

canvas.add (el);
canvas.renderAll ();
```

Comment: @Tom - it would be nice to mark it as answer if it was helpful. thanks

Comment: Thank you, sorry quite busy these days.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done so that you can scale independently.

In the scaling event check the width, height and scale factors, set the height and width to the new effective values and reset the scaleX and scaleY.

This quite probably will break other things that are scaled with the object so you'd have to handle those attributes in a similar fashion.

[Demo Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jesseh77/bH93k/)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c1");

var el = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: "left",
    originY: "top",
    left: 5,
    top: 5,
    stroke: "rgb(0,0,0)",
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cornerSize: 6
});

el.on({
    'scaling': function(e) {
        var obj = this,
            w = obj.width * obj.scaleX,
            h = obj.height * obj.scaleY,
            s = obj.strokeWidth;

        obj.set({
            'height'     : h,
            'width'      : w,
            'scaleX'     : 1,
            'scaleY'     : 1
        });
    }
});

canvas.add (el);
canvas.renderAll ();
```

Comment: Two problems remain (try it with stroke set to 10): 1. move upper left handle and see that the corner at bottom right ist moving too. 2. move any of the handles so that width and/or height gets 0 - if you then move the handle very slowly the object gets suddenly moved instead of resized. I just want to mention it. Unfortunately, I have not enough knowledge to improve your solution.

Comment: Good technique, but does not work properly on polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Fabricjs now has a strokeUniform property on fabric.Rect that can be used to prevent the stroke width from mis-transforming.

When you set strokeUniform to false it will scale with the object if true it will match the pixel size of the stroke width.

```
var el = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: "left",
    originY: "top",
    left: 5,
    top: 5,
    stroke: "#ccc",
    strokWidth: 1,
    fill: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cornerSize: 6,
    strokeUniform: true
});
```