# FabricJS: using object controls on canvas to resize, but not scale

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

The problem is to update the actual `object.width, object.height` and keep `object.scaleX = 1` and `object.scaleY = 1` when using the visual controls on the canvas.

The origin of the problem is when manipulating the object using controls, fabric.js changes the scale of the object, as well as scaling the stroke of paths, which I would like to be of the same width always.

So I would like to make it more like Adobe Illustrator-like, and not scale the width of the stroke along with the width of the rectalngular, for example.

Answer (score 15):

I have found a solution to a question formulated in a different manner here:

[Rect with stroke, the stroke line is mis-transformed when scaled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444817/rect-with-stroke-the-stroke-line-is-mis-transformed-when-scaled)

The idea is to calculate the new would-be width and height using the new scale factors, set the new dimensions and reset the scale factors to 1.

Here's the code example from that answer:

```
el.on({
'scaling': function(e) {
    var obj = this,
        w = obj.width * obj.scaleX,
        h = obj.height * obj.scaleY,
        s = obj.strokeWidth;

    obj.set({
        'height'     : h,
        'width'      : w,
        'scaleX'     : 1,
        'scaleY'     : 1
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 7):

From Fabric.js version 2.7.0 you can enable a `strokeUniform` property on the object this will always match the exact pixel size entered for stroke width.

```
var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 65,
    fill: '#4FC3F7',
    left: 110,
    opacity: 0.7,
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    strokeUniform: true
});
```

http://fabricjs.com/stroke-uniform